# How do I search Firebase to see if a user exists?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to search to see if the email a user types exists in the database, right not Im harding coding the paths. For example my first child is called "User" then it shows an autoID and then "Email" and then the user email. The issue is If I search User and Email the app will crash, it needs the unique ID. Im looking to just check through all the emails to find out if the one the user typed exists

```
- (IBAction)signIn:(id)sender {

    FIRDatabaseReference *usersRef = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

    [[[[usersRef child:@"User"] child:@"-Kx_mPZvAzxZ9U3U0VXq"] child:@"Email"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {


        NSString *record = snapshot.value;
        if(record.length > 0) {
            NSLog(@"%@", record);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"NO");
        }

    }
 ];}
```

Comment: I think `NSString *record = snapshot.value` is wrong way to check `snapshot`. `snapshot` can be `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, `NSNumber`, `NSString`. If `snapshot` isn't a `NSString` and you use record.length, it will cause crash. Try to use `[snapshot exists]` to check snapshot.

Comment: If it doesn't work, can you show me the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass throught all them without knowing the name:

```
FIRDatabaseReference *usersRef = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
let users = 
rootRef.childByAppendingPath(User)
menuItems.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    for id in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FDataSnapshot] {
        //Access to every email here
    }
}
```